# How to include guests and notifications creating a new event in Google Calendar via URL

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

How to include guests and notifications as "GET" parameters when creating a new event in Google Calendar via URL (i.g. https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=test&details=this+is+a+test&location=Italy&dates=20210119T165500Z%2F20210120T165500Z )?

[image: example]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new event you want to use the method [Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) which should be requested [via POST request](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#http-request) to:

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events

It takes several query parameters, but the Event resource (where the attendees are sent) should be passed as the body of the request. Not in the URL.

Comment: I need to share just an URL in which new event I can collaborate/edit event

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you creating the event, or updating it? Here is a link to all the [Events resource methods](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference#Events) as you can see the only GET methods are get, instances and list.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create a custom API to send to your collaborators via GET request. Is that it?

Comment: yes, something like this: www.google/calendar/.../?invite=administrator@domain.com&dates=xxxyyy I need to generate dynamic events on calendar accessible to who clicked on link and managed by administrator who accept the invite (set by GET request)